# Angular HTTP Interceptor logs out user - triggering call retries

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a project with a http interceptor that logs out a user if a http request returns with 401(unauthorized) or 403(forbidden)

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private UNAUTHORIZED_STATES: number[] = [HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden];
    
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (this.UNAUTHORIZED_STATES.includes(err.status)) {
                // auto logout if the api response is in an unathorized status
                this.userService.logout();
            }
            const error = err.error?.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(() => error);
        }));
    }
}
```

This works as expected, the user is logged out correctly, but if the original http call is configured to retry, then the call is retried, even after the user is logged out.

```
this.http.get(apiUrl, { observe: 'response' })
         .pipe(
             retry({ count: 3, delay: 2000}),
             catchError((err) => console.error(err)))
         .subscribe(next: (response: any) => this.handleResponse(response));
```

Can the retry be cancelled by the interceptor?

Comment: Just return an `EMPTY` observable inside your `if` block after logging out the user.